# How to create adaptive frames that work with all iOS screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swiftui, frames, adaptive-layout

I have created a frame that works well with iPhone 13 Pro max. However, the placement is not correct for devices with smaller screens. How can I edit my code, so it adjusts when on a device with a smaller or larger view?

My code:

```
struct GetStartedButton : View
{
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Get Started")
            .frame(width: 352, height: 57)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8470588326454163, green: 0.37254902720451355, blue: 0.27450981736183167, alpha: 1)))
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .padding(.top, 600)
        
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks on a Iphone 13 Pro Max:
[image]

Here is how it looks on a Iphone 8 Plus:
[image]

Comment: Don't hard code any sizes -- use things like `padding` instead to define margins and frame alignments or `Spacer` to define layout.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you desire, the most simple way being probably padding as jnpdx mentioned in the comment. You could also make the frame a certain portion of the screen width. Would look something like this:

```
struct GetStartedButton : View {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Get Started")
            .frame(width: screenSize.width / 1.1, height: screenSize.width / 6.8)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8470588326454163, green: 0.37254902720451355, blue: 0.27450981736183167, alpha: 1)))
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .padding(.top, 600)
    }
}
```

I recommend setting the height parameter of the frame to `screenSize.width` too as not all the devices have the same display aspect ratio, resulting in it looking weird sometimes. Hope this helps!